# Android emulator reboots if I try to fix the gps coordinates

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps

I've created a virtual device with the 2.3 platform (api level 9) and I just launched it and tried to fix GPS location via telnet, as follows:

```
telnet localhost 5554
geo fix 41.41 174.64
```

The emulator returns an "OK" message as the output of my command, and I am simply trying to see if the Google Maps/Latitude app will be able to see these coordinates as my location, but when I load them they will simply reboot the emulator (actually the OS does not come back, I have to close the emulator and launch it again).

Am I doing anything wrong or is there a bug in the emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the emulator. The [issue tracker entry](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13015) has some more information.